# Problem with automatic virtual desktop switching in Kubuntu KDE desktop

Tags: kubuntu, kde, plasma-5, virtualdesktop

I am using Kubuntu flavour
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal

Every time I open something like konsole, vlc player or browser, it switch to another virtual desktop consecutively. I haven't faced this problem earlier, but recently i have been facing this problem a lot. I tried to reset the settings in the virtual desktop, but even though I delete all the virtual desktop, with each started new application, it recreates the virtual desktop and switches automatically.

Is there any possibility to completely remove the virtual desktop or disable it or any helpful tips for this problem?
Thank you

Comment: Please check **Settings → Window Management → Window Rules**. By default it should be empty.

Comment: Yes, window rules seems to be empty. Would you happen to have any other suggestion that I could take look into? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After relentless investigating, it turned out that either **Quick Tile 2** or **Quarter tiling** was somehow seems to be causing the issue. After removing it from kwin script now everything is back to normal again in my case. Hope this helps if someone ends up having similar case.

Quick Tile 2
https://store.kde.org/p/1187647

Quarter Tiling
https://store.kde.org/p/1187647